# React-Native: How it can be added buttons in the application settings iOS?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add some debug information in my application data when you go to Settings -> Your app. I will like to add informations about the application version and a button to delete the application data.

I could not find informations to help me making it. Is it a way to make it?

Comment: wait what? you're talking about the phone settings ?

Comment: I am talking about the application settings. So if you go to Settings and find your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with react-native it self.

You have to follow this guide in order to do so.

Its a bunch of configs in plist files that will enable you to do so.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

After that you use this API to get/set values from keys

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/settings.html

Comment: It has to do a bit with React-Native because I will need to handle it the toggle button.

Comment: Use this API https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/settings.html